# Docker nmap one container from inside another?

Tags: docker, docker-network

I'm trying to understand inter-container communication with Docker.

I have a two containers.

*Container A* has an exposed port which is reachable on `localhost:777`.

So if I use `nmap -p 777 localhost` I can see that the port is open.

I enter *container B*:

```
docker exec -it containerB bash
```

From within *Container B* is it possible for me to use the same `nmap` command from above to see if port 777 on *Container A* is open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this based on information found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach).

From Docker host:

```
sudo ip addr show docker0
```

Take note of docker0 ip address, in my case `172.17.0.1`. Then go into container B with:

```
docker exec -it <container> bash
```

Then:

```
nmap -p 777 172.17.0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

No this would not be possible without the `--network="container:containerA"` arg.

Normally the containers don't share the same network stack. That allows that the same port can be used in multiple containers, but each container has its own localhost.

With the `--network="container:<container>"` arg containerB will share the network stack, so you can use localhost to access the port 777 of containerA.

What you can do without the network arg, and how you should communicate with another container, is to create a network and put both containers in the network (or use links). Then you can access the other container over its name like `nmap -p 777 containerA`

Comment: I'm just about to leave for the day. I'm going to test first thing tomorrow morning and then mark correct. Thanks!